# Swift Structures and classes

Tags: swift, class, structure

What does this line means "Swift doesn’t require you to create separate interface and implementation files for custom structures and classes."
[link](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ClassesAndStructures.html)

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stuck.
So leave a question, show us your code, what did you try and your research:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

It is referring to the old C-style way of separating interfaces and implementations in separate `.h` and `.c` (`.m` for ObjC/`.mm` for ObjC++) files.

In Swift, you no longer need to deal with this - interfaces are generated by the compiler.

For example:

```
public class Loader {
   private let resource: URL
   init(resource: URL) { self.resource = resource }
   public func load { 
     //..
   }
}
```

Generates an interface (effectively, an API) with only the `public` members exposed:

```
public class Loader {
   init(resource: URL)
   public func load()
}
```

The key here is, that there no longer needs to be a separate file maintained by the developer. The interfaces are generated (or not) based on the access control levels defined on your types.

Answer (score 0):

In objective C you have different files for interface called .h file and for implementation of that interface you have .m file
but in swift you have .swift file in which you implement the functionality so you don't need to create two separate files in swift 
thats what docs are referring to ... hope it helps
happy coding =)